# Google App Invite button always leads to Google Play

Tags: android, deep-linking, google-app-invites

I'm implementing Google App Invite mechanism in my application according [documentation](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/app). Invite sending works perfectly, but button "Install" has a very strange behaviour. Early the button worked more or less normal and click on "Install" opened existing app, but sometimes lead to market. But then this button ALWAYS leads to market ignoring fact that application already installed on device. In logs i see every time this action by click "Install" button:

```
I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=package_name&referrer=invitation_id=730634750615-510508a7-7651-4692-a4f8-f221f57b30e2&deep_link_id=http://mydeeplink.com/data flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity (has extras)}
```

What can i do wrong? Why "Install" button click leads to Google Play ignoring installed application on device? Thanks.

Comment: I noticed that after device reboot button "Install" begin works properly for not long time ( And then again leads always to market. Looks like there is some quota for invitations per device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any quota for installs on a device so that is not the problem.

If the app is already installed on the device then it will launch the app, rather than try to install it. The only check is to look for the package already installed on the phone using the package manager. If an email or sms invite finds and launches the installed app after a reboot, but later that same email or sms goes to the play store, then there must be something happening to the status of that app on the phone after it's been running for a while, but that should not occur.

Comment: Thanks @Jim Cunningham!